# Match a pattern not preceded by a quotation mark

Tags: regex, pcre

I have this pattern `(?<!')(\w*)\((\d+|\w+|.*,*)\)` that is meant to match strings like:

- `c(4)`
- `hello(54, 41)`

Following some answers on SO, I added a negative lookbehind so that if the input string is preceded by a `'`, the string shouldn't match at all. However, it still partially matches.

For example:

`'c(4)` returns `(4)` even though it shouldn't match anything because of the negative lookbehind.

How do I make it so if a string is preceded by `'` NOTHING matches?

Comment: Can you explain what `.*` and `,*` are meant to do.

Comment: That's for strings like `hello(54, 12, 515, 51, ...)` And so on. If it helps, look at this pattern as a way to match a string that looks like a function in C-like languages.

Comment: Well, your pattern is somewhat unclear. Actually, changing `*` with `+` with the first `\w` looks to solve the problem, [`(?<!')(\w+)\((\w+|.*,*)\)`](https://regex101.com/r/JbiJQE/1), but the `.*,*` is really strange. Also, there is no point using `d+|\w+` if you are not capturing the data separately, `\w` also matches digits.

Comment: (?<!') is satisfied with `(4)` since `\w` is optional.

Comment: You both are right... Yes - that seemed to be the problem :-)

Comment: No, `.*` and `,*` are not doing what you think.

Comment: Also, functions can have parameters that also call functions, giving nested parenths. If you have a need for that, include that in your problem statement, or start a new one.

Comment: @sln Yes, I'm aware, but this pattern is not meant to match those :-). And what do you mean by `.*` and `,*` not doing what I think?

Comment: `.*` matches anything all the way to the end of string, then backtracks ( like `asdfasf))asfdgasdf))))))))))))))))`, not good). `,*` matches `,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,` You could replace `.*` with `[^)]*` but I don't know what the extent of your targets are.

Comment: Alright, I see what you mean now. That's exactly what I needed. Also, I wish the downvoter cared to explain why the downvote. If there is anything I can do to improve this question for future use I will.

Comment: Just one more thing. If you change it to `(?<!')\w+\(`, etc.., it will still match 'a`b(` if you catch my drift. Better to use `(?<!['\w])\w*\(` <<-- this one.

Comment: Or a word boundary, [`\b(?<!')(\w+)\((\w+|.*,*)\)`](https://regex101.com/r/JbiJQE/2)

Comment: To avoid problems use the one I suggested.

Comment: Thank you again @sln. Perhaps if you wrote an answer I could mark it as the accepted one? :-)

Comment: I don't understand it well enough to write an answer, someone will I'm sure.

Comment: @Morgan If you explain what `.*,*` should match *exactly*, you can get an appropriate answer. `[^)]*` matches any 0+ chars other than `)` and if you have `cp(50, ")", 67)` it will not be matched.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `.*,*` is meant to match an unlimited amount of "words" separated by commas between the parentheses. It was my way of achieving this. I'm a newbie at regex, and I'm sure there's a better way, but that's what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: What are the specs for the "word" bit? Sorry, it is not any better now. If you just say *digit(s)*, or *positive/negative integers/floats*, it would already be something.

Comment: Yes, my bad. It could either be an integer/float or a string. Example: `c(4)`, `c(Morgan)`, `c(45dogcat)`, or `c(dog45, 78cat)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody came along, I'll throw this out to get you started.

This regex will match things like

`aa(a , sd,,,f,)`
`aa( as ,  " ()asdf))  " ,, df, ,   )`
`asdf()`

but not

`'ab(s)`

This will fix the basic problem  `(?<!['\w])\w*`
Where `(?<!['\w])` will not let the engine skip over a word char just
to satisfy the *not quote*.
Then the optional words `\w*` to grab all the words.
And if a `'aaa(` quote is before it, then it won't match.

This regex here embellishes what I think you are trying to accomplish
in the function body part of your regex.
It might be a little overwhelming to understand at first.

`(?s)(?<!['\w])(\w*)\(((?:,*(?&variable)(?:,+(?&variable))*[,\s]*)?)\)(?(DEFINE)(?<variable>(?:\s*(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')\s*|[^()"',]+)))`

Readable version (via: http://www.regexformat.com)

```
 (?s)                          # Dot-all modifier

 (?<! ['\w] )                  # Not a quote, nor word behind
                               # <- This will force matching a complete function name
                               #    if it exists, thereby blocking a preceding quote '

 ( \w* )                       # (1), Function name (optional)
 \(
 (                             # (2 start), Function body
      (?:                           # Parameters (optional)
           ,*                            # Comma (optional)
           (?&variable)                  # Function call, get first variable (required)
           (?:                           # More variables (optional)
                ,+                            # Comma  (required)
                (?&variable)                  # Variable (required)
           )*
           [,\s]*                        # Whitespace or comma (optional)
      )?                            # End parameters (optional)
 )                             # (2 end)
 \)

 # Function definitions
 (?(DEFINE)
      (?<variable>                  # (3 start), Function for a single Variable
           (?:
                \s* 
                (?:                           # Double or single quoted string
                     "                            
                     [^"\\]* 
                     (?: \\ . [^"\\]* )*
                     "
                  |  
                     '                      
                     [^'\\]* 
                     (?: \\ . [^'\\]* )*
                     '
                )
                \s*     
             |                              # or,
                [^()"',]+                     # Not quote, paren, comma (can be whitespace)
           )
      )                             # (3 end)
 )
```